# Add event listener to an element while inserting into CKEDITOR?

Tags: events, ckeditor

I'm newbie to CKEDITOR. It might sound worthless to some of you to answer this questions. But, I'm struggling to find a solution for my problem for the past few hours.

**Aim :**

I would like to add an event listener to particular kind of element ( For ex : `span` )

**What i tried :**

I used `contentDom` event thrown by `CKEDITOR`, to add the event listener to `span` elements.

**Problem :**

However, Adding event listener to `span` will be applicable for the `span` which are currently available in editor. But, Not for the elements ( `span` ) which will be created by the user in future. What should i do now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the benefits of event bubbling [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), [2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/12/an-introduction-to-dom-events/)]. Attach the listener to the topmost element of the editor (editable) and filter out the events:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        contentDom: function() {
            this.editable().on( 'click', function( evt ) {
                var target = evt.data.getTarget();

                if ( target.is( 'span' ) ) {
                    console.log( 'clicked span!' );
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```