# Invoke dialog and fill its content dynamically in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm new to `CKEditor` development. I have written a plugin to insert custom tag element ( `pre` ) and update its attributes.

I want to open the plugin dialog( dialog name is `snippet` ) once user clicks the pre tag element, And i want to fill the `textarea` with clicked element `innerHTML` in dialog.

I have two questions.

1. How to invoke the plugin dialog dynamically?
2. How to access the elements inside the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy the [official plugin development tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1) – there you'll find all the answers. You'll not be able to re-use another plugin's dialog easily though. You need another dialog.

But don't worry, you can copy&paste the source code of [Source Dialog](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sourcearea.html) plugin's [dialog](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/sourcedialog/dialogs/sourcedialog.js), which is very simple, and use it for your plugin. [Code Snippet dialog](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/codesnippet/dialogs/codesnippet.js) is also pretty straightforward.

Also

1. You may find [Developer Tools plugin](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/devtools.html) useful.
2. [You can observe various events with the API of the editor easily (including `click`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416060/add-event-listener-to-an-element-while-inserting-into-ckeditor/27421034#27421034).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

This is not exactly what i'm looking for. I need a method like 
CKEditor.openDialog('dialogname') to invoke dialog from my code.

I knew about code snippet dialog plugin. But, I would like to create my own customised plugin. 

Even in that plugin documentation, They didn't mention about how to access the element inside dialog from some other method.

Comment: Dialogs are opened with pre-defined [`dialogCommands`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialogCommand). You can access current dialog with [`CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-static-method-getCurrent) but if you need to do that, something's wrong with your architecture as dialogs should be controlled with [setup](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2-section-setup-functions) and [commit](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2-section-commit-functions) functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.